# TopologyTestDriver sending incorrect message on KTable aggregations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology that aggregates on a KTable.
This is a generic method I created to build this topology on different topics I have.

```java
public static <A, B, C> KTable<C, Set<B>> groupTable(KTable<A, B> table, Function<B, C> getKeyFunction,
        Serde<C> keySerde, Serde<B> valueSerde, Serde<Set<B>> aggregatedSerde) {
    return table
            .groupBy((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(getKeyFunction.apply(value), value),
                    Serialized.with(keySerde, valueSerde))
            .aggregate(() -> new HashSet<>(), (key, newValue, agg) -> {
                agg.remove(newValue);
                agg.add(newValue);
                return agg;
            }, (key, oldValue, agg) -> {
                agg.remove(oldValue);
                return agg;
            }, Materialized.with(keySerde, aggregatedSerde));
}
```

This works pretty well when using Kafka, but not when testing via `TopologyTestDriver`.

In both scenarios, when I get an update, the `subtractor` is called first, and then the `adder` is called. The problem is that when using the `TopologyTestDriver`, two messages are sent out for updates: one after the `subtractor` call, and another one after the `adder` call. Not to mention that the message that is sent after the `subrtractor` and before the `adder` is in an incorrect stage.

Any one else could confirm this is a bug? I've tested this for both Kafka versions 2.0.1 and 2.1.0.

EDIT: 
I created a testcase in github to illustrate the issue: https://github.com/mulho/topology-testcase

Comment: The testcase link to github is not active anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expected behavior that there are two output records (one "minus" record, and one "plus" record). It's a little tricky to understand how it works, so let me try to explain.

Assume you have the following input table:

```
 key |  value
-----+---------
  A  |  <10,2>
  B  |  <10,3>
  C  |  <11,4>
```

On `KTable#groupBy()` you extract the first part of the value as new key (ie, `10` or `11`) and later sum the second part (ie, `2`, `3`, `4`) in the aggregation. Because `A` and `B` record both have `10` as new key, you would sum `2+3` and you would also sum `4` for new key `11`. The result table would be:

```
 key |  value
-----+---------
  10 |  5
  11 |  4
```

Now assume that an update record `<B,<11,5>>` change the original input KTable to:

```
 key |  value
-----+---------
  A  |  <10,2>
  B  |  <11,5>
  C  |  <11,4>
```

Thus, the new result table should sum up `5+4` for `11` and `2` for `10`:

```
 key |  value
-----+---------
  10 |  2
  11 |  9
```

If you compare the first result table with the second, you might notice that *both* rows got update. The old `B|<10,3>` record is subtracted from `10|5` resulting in `10|2` and the new `B|<11,5>` record is added to `11|4` resulting in `11|9`.

This is exactly the two output records you see. The first output record (after subtract is executed), updates the first row (it subtracts the old value that is not part of the aggregation result any longer), while the second record adds the new value to the aggregation result. In our example, the subtract record would be `<10,<null,<10,3>>>` and the add record would be `<11,<<11,5>,null>>` (the format of those record is `<key, <plus,minus>>` (note that the subtract record only set the `minus` part while the add record only set the `plus` part).

Final remark: it is not possible to put plus and minus records together, because the key of the plus and minus record can be different (in our example `11` and `10`), and thus might go into different partitions. This implies that the plus and minus operation might be executed by different machines and thus it's not possible to only emit one record that contains both plus and minus part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I just wonder why I don't see those when running the actual application, instead of using the TopologyTestDriver. In my case, since I'm not touching the new key (ie, the authorName can never change), does the actual implementation have an optimization to know that the new key is consistent with the previous record, thus this update does not need to be sent as 2 separate messages?

Comment: There should not be any difference, and there should be two messages for both cases (I cannot recall any internal optimization for this case). You say "I don't see those" -- how to do "observe" the output stream?

Comment: My testcase is pretty simple, I have an input topic, read using a KTable that groups and aggregate and send the result to another topic. I simply used the command line to print the messages from the output topic. Also, to make sure it’s not due to the “commit interval”, I,ve put a breakpoint on the aggregation adder and subtractor to add a delay on both, and still no message was published after the subtractor and before the adder.

Comment: Can it be related to caching? TopologyTestDriver `flushes` after each input record. Did you try disabling caching?