# Kafka Streams KGroupedTable.count() returning negative value. How's that possible?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

KGroupedTable.count() is returning negative values?

```
idAndJobTransaction
                .filter((k,v) -> v!=null)
                .mapValues(jobTransaction -> {
                    jobTransaction.setCount(0);
                    jobTransaction.setId(0L);
                    jobTransaction.setRunsheet_id(0L);
                    jobTransaction.setTimestamp(0L);
                    if(jobTransaction.getDelete_flag() == 1)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return jobTransaction;
                } )
                .groupBy((id,jobTransaction)->new KeyValue<>(jobTransaction,jobTransaction),Serialized.with(jobTransactionSerde,jobTransactionSerde))
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .mapValues((k,v)-> new JobSummary(k,v))
                .peek((k,v)->{
                    log.info(k.toString());
                    log.info(v.toString());
                }).selectKey((k,v)-> v.getCompany_id())  // So that the count is consumed in order for each company
                .to(JOB_SUMMARY,Produced.with(Serdes.Long(),jobSummarySerde));
```

The count method is sometimes returning negative values.  Around 1% percent of the values are negative. How is that possible?

EDIT 1:

I push the results of this aggregation to a Postgres table. The negative values are not limited to -1 but it goes to very high values.

I am using 2 consumers. Does that make any difference?

Can it be an issue with Kafka streams? or should I look into other possible reasons?

[image]

EDIT 3:
I was able to capture some of the available logs and I did see the negative values in the peek:

[image]

As for the JobSummary class, Its really a very simple POJO class. Here's the constructor called in the KStream app.

```
  public JobSummary(JobTransaction j, Long count){
    this.setUser_id(j.getUser_id());
    this.setHub_id(j.getHub_id());
    this.setCity_id(j.getCity_id());
    this.setCompany_id(j.getCompany_id());
    this.setJob_master_id(j.getJob_master_id());
    this.setJob_status_id(j.getJob_status_id());
    this.setCount(count);
    this.setDate(j.getDate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess (it's the only explanation I can come up with), that this is a special corner case. First you have to understand how a `KTable` aggregation work internally. This is explained on a different question: [TopologyTestDriver sending incorrect message on KTable aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372134/topologytestdriver-sending-incorrect-message-on-ktable-aggregations)

With this background, a negative count can happen, if the current count in the result table is zero, and the upstream base-table (ie, `idAndJobTransaction`) gets an idempotent update (ie, a record in the base-table is updated from `<K,V>` to `<K,V>`. This would result in one subtraction and one addition record that go to the same row in the result table (note, that Kafka Streams does not compare old and new value on a table update and blindly assumes that both are different). Also, subtraction and addition record are sent downstream independently and the downstream `count()` updates its result in two steps. Thus, the count in the result table goes from 0 to -1 processing the subtraction record and goes back from -1 to 0 processing the addition record.

Comment: But the eventual result should always be more than or equal to zero. shouldn't it?

Comment: I have added some more details in the question itself.

Comment: Yes, it should always go back to zero. I have no idea atm, how you could end up with counts less than -1... Can you confirm that the problem is with `count()` by doing `count().toStream().print()` -- maybe it's messed up after the count.

Comment: Could this be a serde issue?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I will add additional logs and get back to you. 
The chances are less since there's no processing after the count is calculated, it's simply dumped into Postgres. I will add logs and get back to you.
I will get back to you by Monday as I am out of town this weekend.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky: I highly doubt that since only 1% of the values are showing negative values. I suspect there would be many errors if that was the case.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax : Hi Matthias, I didn't see any negative values with a small change in the code from the last 2 days.  If you can see that I used the object jobTransaction in the groupBy method, I changed it to JSON String representation of the same object and It seems that it solved the problem. 
Does this information somehow explain the behavior before?

Comment: I don't have  good idea atm. If you can reproduce the issue in an IDE, I would recommend to set a breakpoint in `KTableAggregateProcessor#processor` (nested class within `KTableAggregate.java`). What you can also try it, to use interactive queried to get the count from the underlying state store to see how those are updated (similarly, you could consumer the corresponding changelog topic to see what's written into the store---disabling caching might help to get a cleaner picture here). Hope this helps.